# Correct way to check if a DOM element object has a certain method?

Tags: javascript

On the Android Stock Browser I get "has no method 'click'" on some DOM elements (like the **a** tag) while it works on other browser. Therefore I'm trying to create a conditional to check if the method exists. This is what I've got so far:

```
<a href="test" id="test">test</a>

if (typeof document.getElementById('test').click === 'function') {
    alert('it has');
} else {
    alert('it has not');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Acejt/1/

This seems to be working but I want to know if it's the correct way of doing it and if it's cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Looks fine. Without HTML and selecting something, you might also use `document.createElement("a").click`

Answer (score 5):

Try this to list all element's methods:

```
var el= document.getElementById('test');
for(var i in el){
    if(typeof el[i] == "function")
    console.log(i + " is function. ") //+ el[i])
}
```

In the same way you can check if method exists before using it:

```
if( typeof el["click"] == "function")
 el.click();
```

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to want to list all methods. Why are you suggesting it?

Comment: @FelixKling Hello Felix , you're right , i've just edited my answer

Comment: Thanks! Is this better than the method in my original post?

Comment: @user1767586: I don't see any difference.

Comment: @user1767586 yours even stronger because of `===` !